# pyspark - Editor taking longer time than Jupyter Notebook

Tags: pycharm, pyspark, pydev, jupyter

I have a python-spark code which reads data from file, performs operations on the data & writes back to file.

When I run this script in my editor (PyDev, eclipse) it is taking 4s while the same code is taking 0.4s in Jupyter Notebook.

I have tried using pycharm ide too, issue still exist.

Can someone help me figure out the reason behind.

Comment: I'm facing similar issue with iPython Vs pycharm. I've tried checking spark.master, it is local[4] for both. Unable to figure out.

Comment: In jupyter, the PySpark kernel is already active. In pycharm or pydev, the SparkContext needs initialized. Does that help?

Comment: @cricket_007 yeah, it is obvious that some part of the time is taken for initializing spark context, sometimes the time difference in 7mins (notebook) Vs 14mins (editor). Any inferences ?

Comment: I haven't seen anything that drastic, at least not locally. But just starting the PySpark shell itself takes a couple seconds

Comment: for me it's taking same time both using spark-submit (commandline) & editor, could be because of SC initialization

Comment: I suggest you profile to see the difference (anything else is just a guess). If you use PyDev, you can install http://www.pyvmmonitor.com and use the trial (and then, when launching just say that you want to run with the profiler in the profile view: http://www.pyvmmonitor.com/pydev_integration.html)